# minimum numbers of boats to carry every person

Tags: java, algorithm

The i-th person has weight people[i], and each boat can carry a maximum weight of limit.

Each boat carries at most 2 people at the same time, provided the sum of the weight of those people is at most limit.

Return the minimum number of boats to carry every given person.  (It is guaranteed each person can be carried by a boat.)

Example 1:

> Input: people = [1,2], limit = 3
>   Output: 1
>   Explanation: 1 boat (1, 2)

Example 2:

> Input: people = [3,2,2,1], limit = 3
>   Output: 3
>   Explanation: 3 boats (1, 2), (2) and (3)

Example 3:

> Input: people = [3,5,3,4], limit = 5
>   Output: 4
>   Explanation: 4 boats (3), (3), (4), (5)

I am getting the wrong output for 2nd example 
getting output 2 instead 3 
whats wrong with my code 
I want the code in this way

```
class Solution {
    public int numRescueBoats(int[] people, int limit) {
        int count = 0;
        int i;
        int j = people.length - 1;

        Arrays.sort(people);

        for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {
            if (people[i] + people[j] <= limit) {
                i++;
                j--;
            } else {
                j--;
            }

            count++; 
        }

        return count;
    }
}
```

example 2 getting output `2` instead `3`

Comment: I recommend you edit your title because the title is very general

Comment: ok , done......

Comment: answer please..

Comment: To me your logic is not correct, people[i]+people[j] <=limit, so when you check for single person?? you didn't include it here,

Comment: Answer what? You haven't asked a question. You've written out  your assignment (but you've not said it was homework, and you [really should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/740553)), you've shown code, and you've written nothing else that constitutes a question. Is there something wrong with the Solution you've written? As a new user, _please_ remember to read through [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and make your question follow those principles so that people can actually help you.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I believe his question is why their example 2 outputs the incorrect number. Could be clearer though.

Comment: Please _also_ read the Stackoverflow [code of conduct](/conduct) that we're all expected to follow. You're a new user to the site, and while it's easy to think you know how to write a post because of the ones you've already read year in year out, there are still policies for you to follow when posting a question. You're asking _real people_ for help, so help them help you by remembering the SO policies and following them when asking questions. We have these policies because asking questions on SO is not just "for you", it's for everyone who comes to SO hoping to find an answer to this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your loop part with this one:

```
for (i = 0; i < j; ) {
            if (people[i] + people[j] <= limit) {
                i++;
                j--; 

            } 
            else {

                 j--;
             }
             count++;
        }
```

Comment: It gives wrong result when I ran it on OP's input after sorting it.

Comment: Check you code, or post the full code as answer, I will check, @Madstuffs

Comment: `    class Solution {
      public int numRescueBoats(int[] people, int limit)  {
        int count=0;
        int i=0;
        int j = people.length-1;
     Arrays.sort(people);
        while( i<=j){
            
            if(people[i]+people[j]<=limit){
                
                i++;
                j--;
               // count++;
            }
            
            else{
                j--;
            }
                    count++;
                
        }
        return count;
    }
    }`

Answer (score 1):

1) You increment `i` twice in successful `if` and 1 time in unsuccessful. You should remove `i++` inside `for` statement to prevent double increment.

2) You don't check last single person - change comparison `for (i = 0; i < j; i++) {` to `for (i = 0; i <= j;) {`.

Comment: How it works without checking single weight, could you explain @Naveen Verma

Comment: `class Solution { 
    public int numRescueBoats(int[] people, int limit) {
        int count=0;
        int i=0;
        int j = people.length-1;
     Arrays.sort(people);
        while( i<=j){
            
            if(people[i]+people[j]<=limit){
                
                i++;
                j--;
               // count++;
            }
            
            else{
                j--;
            }
                    count++;
                
        }
        return count;
    }
}`